# Optimizing Javascript and CSS used BY my web site but not located ON my website?

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, compression, pagespeed

I have a *Contact Us* plugin on my website. It's made and operated by Dropifi. Recently I've been trying to optimize my site for SEO/Speed with googles PageSpeed Insights tool. Now, I've enabled compression using with GZip for everything on my site, but google is pointing out .js and .css files located on Dropifis site as necessary to compress. Its also asking me to leverage browser caching for files on their site as well. Is there ANY way to help this without removing the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You could use both [cssminifier.com](http://cssminifier.com) and [javascript-minifier.com](http://javascript-minifier.com) and their "API".

Just send a POST-Request to http://cssminifier.com/raw?input=YOURCSSFILE and http://javascript-minifier.com/raw?input=YOURJSFILE and you receive the compressed version.

Notice that I'm not sure, if they are fast enough to achieve an improvement, but the CSS and JS Code will be compressed, just the way you want it.

Comment: To reiterate, I don't have access to these files. I've pasted an example below:

Compressing https://www.dropifi.com/…essenger/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css could save 92.6KiB (83% reduction).

This is on Dropifis server, not mine. I don't have access to it. My question was whether or not there is a workaround.

Comment: In your PHP Code - or somewhere else - you could get the Content of that file, POST it to the Pages I mentioned above, and include that result as your new CSS and JS Files.